# Percentile Python, problems Setting values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im calculating percentiles and doing some operations along too many columns.

```
perc = np.percentile([100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,300,123,124,90,98,999,567,345],[20,40,60,80])
print(perc)
array([100., 100., 123., 300.])
```

I need to get the unique values then, setting my vector i got this:

```
set(perc)
{100.0, 123.0, 300.0}
```

It works in almost all of the columns, but for any reason i got columns with this issue:

```
perc_1 = np.percentile([100,100,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf],[20,40,60,80])
```

then calculating percentiles:

```
print(perc_1)
array([ nan, 100.,  nan,  nan])
```

then, setting this vector i got this:

```
set(perc_1)
{nan, nan, 100.0, nan}
```

Setting doesnt work.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `nan` values, which are float, are not equal even to themselves, you can use code below:

```py
perc_1 = np.percentile([100,100,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf],[20,40,60,80])
list(filter(lambda x: x==x, list(set(perc_1))))
```

##### Output

```
[100.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to replace nan and inf to preserve those values.

> set(None if np.isnan(x) or np.isinf(x) else x for x in perc_1)

which is
`{100.0, None}`